# Count(t.id) AS count on join causing two `count` columns?

Tags: mysql

`Count(t.id) AS count on join` causing two columns named `count` but the first column is all 0.
**What is causing the duplicate error with empty column?**

```
SELECT t . * , COUNT(t.id) AS count
FROM (
SELECT  `id` ,  `date` 
FROM  `searches` 
WHERE  `date` > '2016-12-06'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10000
) q
JOIN  `searches` t ON t.id = q.id
GROUP BY  `query` 
ORDER BY  `count` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

*Image shows count column with all 0's should not be showing up in temp table.*

[image: count column with all 0's should not be showing up in temp table.]

**BONUS:**  Is there an obvious way to speed up this query?

Showing rows 0 - 29 (30 total, Query took 0.2904 sec)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Thanks but the image is not code, but the results of the sql query to show the 2 columns that are appearing.  Table structure included for bonus question.

Comment: As show in the link explain , we cant copy / paste the data from image to test the query. Also please be clear on what is the source data and what is the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `t.*` in your first line, you are pulling in every column from the table.  This would include the count column.  Then you are calculating a count named count.  That is why you have two count columns.  The count column in your table probably has all zeros inserted into it.

If you do not want the column with all zeros, you must make you query look like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.ip, t.fbuild, t.useragent, t.query , COUNT(t.id) AS count
FROM (
SELECT  `id` ,  `date` 
FROM  `searches` 
WHERE  `date` > '2016-12-06'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10000
) q
JOIN  `searches` t ON t.id = q.id
GROUP BY  `query` 
ORDER BY  `count` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a column called `count` in your `searches` table which you've aliased `t` in your query. `t.*` appears in your select column list and so the `count` from your `searches` table is pulled in. The second `count` comes your aggregate.